# Submit form with validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-typescript

I'm working on this code to submit a form using React with Typescript and Material-UI:

```
export default function OpenTicket(props: any) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const formHandler = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.target);
    };

    return (

            <Container>
                <Box m={5}>
                    <div className={classes.root}>
                      <form>

                            <TextField
                              id="outlined-full-width"
                              label="Name"                                                    
                              />
                            <Button
                               variant="contained">
                               Submit
                            </Button> 
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </Box>
            </Container>
    );
}
```

Request:

```
export interface TicketDTO {
    title?: string;
}

export async function postTicket(): Promise<AxiosResponse<TicketDTO[]>> {
  return await axios.post<TicketDTO[]>(
    `${baseUrl}/support/tickets/create`
  );
}
```

What is the proper way to implement a field validation and make a call when Submit button is pressed?

Comment: I know this might not be what you're expecting but normally when I'm working with forms I like to use react-hook-form, it allows you to do input validation, with a lot of options, plus it is a light library that integrates very easily with your code and external libraries.

Comment: Can you show me code example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your comment, this is how you usually would use react-hook-form:

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();

  // This won't be run unless all the input validations are met.
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input {...register("firstName", { required: true, maxLength: 20 })} />
      {errors.firstName && <span>This field is required</span>}
      <input {...register("lastName", { pattern: /^[A-Za-z]+$/i })} />
      {errors.lastName && <span>This field can't be a number</span>}
      <input type="number" {...register("age", { min: 18, max: 99 })} />
      {errors.age && <span>This needs to be between 18 and 99 range</span>}
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

The register function is the one that handles the validation, you can read all the available validations here.

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register

I think this eliminates a lot of code duplication to handle the inputs using react state, plus it also makes the validation and integration with external UI libraries very easy.

I have this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-bohr-lk6ki) in case you want to see the code in action.

**Edit:**

To perform a post request like the one in your question, and using the typing that you used, you can do something like this:

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import "./styles.css";

interface TicketDTO {
  title: string;
}

async function postTicket(
  data: TicketDTO
): Promise<AxiosResponse<TicketDTO[]>> {
  return await axios.post<TicketDTO[]>(`baseUrl/support/tickets/create`);
}

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
    // This generic will type the data response correctly.
    // So the errors object and register function will infer the types of TicketDTO.
  } = useForm<TicketDTO>();

  // This won't be run unless all the input validations are met.
  const onSubmit = async (data: TicketDTO) => {
  // This console.log won't give errors
  // console.log(data.title);
  // This console.log will give typing errors
  // console.log(data.randomValue);
    try {
      await postTicket(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input {...register("title", { required: true, maxLength: 20 })} />
      {errors.title && <span>This field is required</span>}
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Here's the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-engelbart-clc74) and the post is not working because there's no valid base url, but it should do what you want to.

**Edit without react hook form.**

This example uses react state and as I mention is more work to do since you will have to do the validations by yourself.

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import React from "react";

import "./styles.css";

interface TicketDTO {
  title: string;
}

async function postTicket(
  data: TicketDTO
): Promise<AxiosResponse<TicketDTO[]>> {
  return await axios.post<TicketDTO[]>(`baseUrl/support/tickets/create`);
}

export default function App() {
 // You will have to define your custom fields in separate states or one object state. this uses a separate state per input.
  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState("");
  // You will have to define the errors as well.
  const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState<TicketDTO>({
    title: ""
  });
  const onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
    setTitle(event.target.value);

  const onSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    // Prevents browser to load the document
    event.preventDefault();
    // Here you will have to do logic to handle all your inputs.
    if (title) {
      try {
        await postTicket({ title });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      setErrors({ title: "" });
    } else {
      setErrors({ title: "Title is required" });
    }
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input name="title" value={title} onChange={onChange} />
      {errors.title && <span>This field is required</span>}
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Also you can take advantage of the HTML5 native [validations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) if you don't want to do the validations in react. so it is just a matter of doing this:

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import React from "react";

import "./styles.css";

interface TicketDTO {
  title: string;
}

async function postTicket(
  data: TicketDTO
): Promise<AxiosResponse<TicketDTO[]>> {
  return await axios.post<TicketDTO[]>(`baseUrl/support/tickets/create`);
}

export default function App() {
  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState("");
  const onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
    setTitle(event.target.value);

  const onSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    // Prevents browser to load the document
    event.preventDefault();
      try {
        await postTicket({ title });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      {/* required prop makes usage of native html5 validation */}
      <input name="title" value={title} required onChange={onChange} />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you show me also how to make the API POST call?

Comment: @PeterPenzov just updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you. It's much more clear. Just in case can you show me code example without this `react-hook-form` library, please? I'm not sure I'm allowed to use it in my project.

Comment: I will update, but keep in mind this is the most basic example and validations are handled by you in the submit function

Comment: Hey @PeterPenzov updated the answer with native html5 validation and custom react validation.